# Ionic bottom navigation bar (Android 10) styling

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am wondering if anyone has figured out how to style a bottom navigation bar in Ionic/Cordova.

This bar only appears on Android 10 when you enable swipe gestures instead of three-button UI, see screenshot below.

[image]